# transpose a list into a column without the list being in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list. it is text, how do I input this list as a straight list in on line in vba, in such a way that vba automatically transposes this list into a column, in which each text value is below the previous ofin that list?

this list does not exist in excel, it will solely be typed in vba.

Comment: see dictionary collections or arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
MyList = [{"a";"b";"c";"d";"e"}]
```

This will create a vertical array with five rows and one column. The square brackets are an abbreviated notation for the Evaluate method.

The abbreviated notation has a couple of limitations. The text inside the square brackets must be literal and must be shorter than 256 characters.

For longer lists you can use the full Evaluate method.

Comment: thanks for the reply, however this has failed to work for me
this is what I wrote: Range("a2").Value = [{"a";"b";"c";"d";"e"}]                         where did I go wrong?

Comment: Range("a2:a6") = [{"a";"b";"c";"d";"e"}]

Comment: @DaaB Did you get it working?

Comment: Yes! it works, thanks for the help

Comment: @DaaB Great. Please accept the answer by clicking the big check mark next to the answer.

Comment: I have a follow up question...how do I use the full evaluate method in the same manner and structure?